# pillow image TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am a bit lost as to why this is happening any help would be greatly appreciated. So I am trying to take the median value of images and create a new image from them, but when trying to make newpix take in the values of my red green and blue median pixel the error:

TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

happens

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops,ImageDraw,ImageFilter
import math
import glob
import os.path
from os import  listdir;
import numpy


image_list = []

redPixels = []
greenPixels = []
bluePixels = []

for filename in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\Proj1\images\*.png"):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
im = Image.open(open(r"C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\Proj1\images\1.png",'rb'))
width, height = im.size
print(height)
print (width)

result = Image.new('RGB', (width,height))
newpix = result.load()
for x in range (width):
    for y in range (height):
        for z in (image_list):
            red  = z.getpixel((x,y))
            blue = z.getpixel((x,y))
            green = z.getpixel((x,y))

            redPixels.append(red)
            greenPixels.append(green)
            bluePixels.append(blue)
        red = sorted(redPixels)
        blue = sorted(bluePixels)
        green = sorted(greenPixels)

        mid = int( (len(image_list)+1)/2)-1

        newRed = redPixels[mid]
        newBlue = bluePixels[mid]
        newGreen = greenPixels[mid]
        newpix[x,y] = (newRed,newGreen,newBlue)

result.save("Stacked.png")
```

Comment: Need full stack trace

Comment: Could you explain? I am a bit lost. be_good_do_good

Comment: Can you post full error that you get on console. Full stack trace will have the call flow as well

Comment: Is your error at range(width)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\Proj1\from PIL import Image", line 45, in <module>
    newpix[x,y] = value
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Comment: Working on the problem

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Second to last line something like this: `newpix[x,y] = newRed << 16 + newGreen << 8 + newBlue`

Comment: Posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is at the lines

```
        red  = z.getpixel((x,y))
        blue = z.getpixel((x,y))
        green = z.getpixel((x,y))

        redPixels.append(red)
        greenPixels.append(green)
        bluePixels.append(blue)
```

`red = z.getpixel((x,y))` will get all R,G,B data at x,y position, so it will be tuple like (255,255,255). Hence making changes to your code like below made it work:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops,ImageDraw,ImageFilter
import math
import glob
import os.path
from os import  listdir;
import numpy


image_list = []

redPixels = []
greenPixels = []
bluePixels = []

for filename in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\Proj1\images\*.png"):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
im = Image.open(open(r"C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\Proj1\images\1.png",'rb'))
width, height = im.size
print(height)
print (width)

result = Image.new('RGB', (width,height))
newpix = result.load()
for x in range (width):
    for y in range (height):
        for z in (image_list):
            rgb  = z.getpixel((x,y))
            redPixels.append(rgb[0])
            greenPixels.append(rgb[1])
            bluePixels.append(rgb[2])
        red = sorted(redPixels)
        blue = sorted(bluePixels)
        green = sorted(greenPixels)

        mid = int( (len(image_list)+1)/2)-1
        newRed = redPixels[mid]
        newBlue = bluePixels[mid]
        newGreen = greenPixels[mid]

        newpix[x,y] = (newRed,newGreen,newBlue)

result.save("Stacked.png")
```

Comment: Thanks alot but i figured it out about 30 minutes after posting.