# Adding text in an image using open cv

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror

I am tracking objects using open cv. I went through a code in the internet. While I am running that it shows some error like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/Pi-tracker-master/obj.py", line 32, in <module>
    cv2.putText(img, str(i+1),font,(x,y+h),(0,255,255))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

and I found one answer for that error in stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652480/pillow-image-typeerror-an-integer-is-required-got-type-tuple) but I am not clear about that one.

code I am using :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

lowerBound=np.array([33,80,40])
upperBound=np.array([102,255,255])

cam= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
kernelOpen=np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose=np.ones((20,20))

font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2,0.5,0,3,1

while True:
    ret, img=cam.read()
    img=cv2.resize(img,(340,220))

    #convert BGR to HSV
    imgHSV= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # create the Mask
    mask=cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lowerBound,upperBound)
    #morphology
    maskOpen=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
    maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)

    maskFinal=maskClose
    _,conts,h=cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    cv2.drawContours(img,conts,-1,(255,0,0),3)
    for i in range(len(conts)):
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(i+1),font,(x,y+h),(0,255,255))
    cv2.imshow("maskClose",maskClose)
    cv2.imshow("maskOpen",maskOpen)
    cv2.imshow("mask",mask)
    cv2.imshow("cam",img)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Comment: There are logical issues in the code.. Basically what you done will go to an infinite loop..
Will share one of my working prototype with put text shortly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code

```
font                   = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
bottomLeftCornerOfText = (10,500)
fontScale              = 1
fontColor              = (255,255,255)
lineType               = 2

cv2.putText(img,'Some text', 
    bottomLeftCornerOfText, 
    font, 
    fontScale,
    fontColor,
    lineType)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your parameters in the wrong order. Your tuple `(x,y+h)` is in the position where a font is expected (fonts are just encoded as integers if I recall correctly). [`putText`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#void%20putText(Mat&%20img,%20const%20string&%20text,%20Point%20org,%20int%20fontFace,%20double%20fontScale,%20Scalar%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20bool%20bottomLeftOrigin)) expects input in this order:

> Python: cv2.putText(img, text, org, fontFace, fontScale, color[, thickness[, lineType[, bottomLeftOrigin]]]) → None

You just need to match this. For instance:

```
cv2.putText(img, str(i+1),(x,y+h),font,1,(0,255,255))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code with put text.
Please take reference from the below and do necessary changes to your code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

lowerBound=np.array([33,80,40])
upperBound=np.array([102,255,255])

cam= cv2.VideoCapture('1.mp4')
kernelOpen=np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose=np.ones((20,20))

font                   = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
bottomLeftCornerOfText = (10,500)
fontScale              = 1
fontColor              = (255,255,255)
lineType               = 2

ret, img = cam.read()
while ret:  
    img=cv2.resize(img,(340,220))
    cv2.putText(img,'Hello World!', 
    bottomLeftCornerOfText, 
    font, 
    fontScale,
    fontColor,
    lineType)
    ret, img=cam.read()
```